# FSCalendar changing Reveal Controller Menu to gray color

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, swrevealviewcontroller, fscalendar

I'm a newbie to IOS. I'm using [Reveal Controller](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) (as Left side navigation menu) and [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) (to show a different kind of events) for my app. My Menu contains a submenu. One of the list in the submenu is the View controller that consists of FSCalendar. Now, When I click the FSCalendar option, the entire menu is turning into the gray color as shown in below screenshot. How to fix it? Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: are you used the uilabel apperance tintcolor property any where

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik You mean in Reveal Controller or in FSCalendar?

Comment: in FSCalendar..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm using following override methods in FSCalendar.
(UIColor *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance titleDefaultColorForDate:(NSDate *)date

 (UIColor *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance fillDefaultColorForDate:(NSDate *)date

(UIColor *)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar appearance:(FSCalendarAppearance *)appearance borderDefaultColorForDate:(NSDate *)date

Comment: ya check once appearance color, it is affected in another color

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Where I check appearance color in FSCalendar?

Comment: sorry my bro, in before i am not get the chance to work with FSCalendar, but i can understand the problem , you need to check appearance color gray color where you set in your VC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143784/discussion-between-dinesh-and-anbu-karthik).